# Integrating a Poisson kernel in $n$ dimensional unit sphere

Tags: partial-differential-equations, harmonic-functions

Let 
\begin{equation*}
P(x,y)=\frac{1}{\omega_n R} \frac{R^2-|x|^2}{|x-y|^n}
\end{equation*}
be a Poisson kernel where $x$, $y$ are in $R^n$, $|x|<R$, $|y|=R$, $\omega_n$ is area of n dimensional unit sphere. 
Then what is $$\int_{\partial B_1(0)}P(x,y)dA_y=?$$

Comment: Do you want to integrate over $x$? (You said $|y|=R$)

Comment: No, I mean the boundary of the unit ball. I forgot to put boundary mark on it. Sorry

Comment: And in this case, R=1

Answer (score 1):

Hint: The function

$$g(x) = \int_{\partial B_1(0)} P(x, y) dA_y = \int_{\partial B_1(0)}  1 \cdot P(x, y) dA_y$$

satisfies $\Delta g = 0$ in $B_1(0)$ and $g(y) = 1$ on $\partial B_1(0)$. What can $g$ be?

Comment: well, can't we actually compute the integral? From the solution of Poisson equation, i know that if the harmonic function is constant 1 then it satisfies g=1. But I want to see what actually happens

Comment: I guess it will be quite difficult to compute the integral directly. @amen

Answer (score -3):

"P(x,y)= (omega[n]R ())^(-1)(R^(2)-|x|( )^(2))|x-y|( )^(^(-n) ) ,

```
  |x-y(|)^(2)=|x|^(2)-2|x|R costheta +R^(2), for x*y =|x|R costheta "
```

"dsigma[n]=sin^(n-2)theta dtheta dsigma[n-1] for functions depending only on

theta, where dsigma[n] denotes Lebesgue measure on S( )^(n) , thus get

integral of type ∫(a+b*costheta)^(-n)sin^(n-2)theta dtheta from 0 to

Pi,, which can be evaluated by well known substitution tan(theta/(2))=u,

get ∫(1+u^(2))^(2) u^(n-2)(A+u^(2))^(-n)du from 0 to 1 which can be

evaluated by calculus of residues,  also note Claus Mueller, Spherical

harmonics, Lecture Notes v.42 ("?) ""

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{a4paper}

```
\begin{document}
```

$P(x,y)=(\omega_n R)^{-1}(R^2-|x|^2)|x-y|^{-n}$,$x*y=|x|R\cos\theta$,$ |x-y|^2=|x|^2-2|x|R\cos\theta+R^2$, $d\sigma_n=\sin^{n-2}\theta d\theta d\sigma_{n-1}$ for integrands depending on $\theta$ only, where $\sigma_n$ denotes Lebesgue measure on $S^{n-1}$, thus get integral of type $\int^\pi_0 (a+b\cos\theta)^{-n}\sin^{n-2}\theta d\theta$, (wlog $R=1$, and x in same direction as North pole of coordinate system (turn coordinate system around) so that $\theta$ also is angle between $x$ and $y$) which can be evaluated by $\tan \theta/ 2=u$, get $\int_0^\infty(1+u^2)^2u^{n-2}(A+u^2)^{-n}du$ which can be evaluated by residue calculus, also see Claus M\''uller, Spherical Harmonics (search Internet).
\end{document}

Comment: Its really hard to read your answer. At the very least please type it with MathJax, see here for a tutorial https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Comment: Some specific points for your editing; 1. you don't need `\begin{document}` or `\usepackage{...}`. On this website, MathJax is used, so these are automatic for most things, as you can already see. 2. You can use `$$...$$` (but not `\[...\]`) to make math display in `\displaystyle`, which I would suggest because your answer has a lot of symbols that make the line look cramped when used inline. 3. You'll need to type Müller, since \"u doesn't work. And if I may be so bold; if you're able to copy-paste an entire $\LaTeX$ document, you can also search for the link to these notes by Müller, right?

Comment: reference is to Claus  Müller, Spherical Harmonics, Lecture Notes in Mathematics vol.42 (an old text, available in libraries), also at least one more correction:after the top lines already R is taken as 1

Comment: Mentioned old text supplied as general reference, given the kernel in spherical coordinates any user with calculus background including functions of 1 complex variable can find and check suggested method of evaluation.

Comment: in other words user doubts that Müller, Spherical Harmonics has any desired details of computation, in fact that the author even considers the question at hand